# Is there a way to make Stylus use src and dest paths that don't contain a "stylesheets" directory?

Tags: node.js, stylus

I've recently begun using Node and Stylus and run into this issue.  I want to keep my generated css in /public/css, not /public/stylesheets, and it seems that the Stylus configuration options won't allow for that.

```
// ... your middleware here
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/views',     // .styl files are located in `views/stylesheets`      
    dest: __dirname + '/public',   // .styl resources are compiled `/stylesheets/*.css`     
    compile: function(str, path) {
        return stylus(str)
            .set('filename', path)
            .set('warn', true)
            .set('compress', true);
    }
}));
```

The comments in the above code are from a Stylus example.  For the src and dest properties, "/stylesheets" is automatically appended (as the comments from the original example imply).  This seems unnecessary and I guess I'm wondering if there's just a way to turn that off.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment, from what I gather from pull request [#128](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/pull/210). The workaround is nesting an extra directory to match the path generated by the middleware, which seems uglier than the problem itself.

Assuming that your HTTP request path is `/css/file.css`, you dir structure should look like this:

```
/view/stylesheets/css/*.styl
/public/css/*.css
```

and your middleware config should look like this:

```
debug: true,   // Set this flag to see what the middleware is doing
src: __dirname + '/views/stylesheets',
dest: __dirname + '/public',
```

(I haven't tried this, but point is to match what the middleware expects.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  src: __dirname + '/views/stylesheets',
  dest: __dirname + '/public/css',
```

Looking at the code:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/middleware.js

That should work as the stylus file relative path (to src dir) no longer contains stylesheets. Nothing is appended per se.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I tested these settings: "src: __dirname + '/views', dest: __dirname + '/public'", and it pulled from /views/stylesheets and generated to /public/stylesheets.  So that path is being appended somehow.  It doesn't do anything when I change dest to __dirname + '/public/css' and set my css include to /css/main.css.

Comment: In other words the relative path was [sourcedir]/stylesheets/main.styl and it output to [destdir]/stylesheets/main.css, exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue like this . I used `src` as function .. eg : your http request path is

```
GET /css/style.css
```

then replace `/css` and locate into `stylesheets` folder.

```
app.use(stylus.middleware({
   src: function( path ){
       // print it for debug
       console.log( path );
       return  require('path').join(
           __dirname + '/views/stylesheets',
           path.replace('/css' ,'').replace('.css', '.styl')
       );
   },
   dest:__dirname + '/public' ,
   debug: true,
   ...
```

it will generate css files under folder `__dirname + '/public/css/`

**or**

create a folder `css` under `__dirname + '/views/stylesheets'` and move `*.styl` files into it

```
app.use(stylus.middleware({
   src: __dirname + '/views/stylesheets',
   dest:__dirname + '/public' ,
   debug: true,
   ...
```